# Router behind router network setup

Tags: networking, router, remote-access

My relative has bought a router instead of a switch which causes remote-access control issues on his network.

His existing network has a 1st router where all PCs are connected via LAN cables. The 2nd router connnects to the 1st router and the remaining PCs are connected to the 2nd router via LAN cables.

Normally, I would perform remote-access to help him out with some task. Now it seems all services behind the 2nd router are unavailable to me.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the edge router into bridge mode, Disable DHCP and configure the second to function as  the DHCP server/port forwarder. Sometimes this option isn't available in consumer grade router/modems so your relative may find it easier to return the router and purchase a switch. Also keep in mind that even though having two routers on your network technically works, it really is wrecking bandwidth throughput due to a double NAT situation.

Comment: which is the edge router? the 2nd router?

Comment: It would be the router that connects to the modem or if applicable, the router/modem that handles the internet connection.

Comment: "Edge" is a term that indicates the device at the edge of your network, the one that faces the public or other outside entities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_device

Comment: I thought the 2nd router should be set as bridge mode.

Comment: I suppose it makes no difference which router you configure as a bridge - either setup should work. Keep in mind the bridged router will essentially function as a layer 2 switch with no routing features. All port forwarding is configured on the other (non-bridged) router.